# create woocommerce product from the front-end

Tags: product, woocommerce, frontend

I am currently trying allow wordpress users to create woocommerce  product  from the front-end using WP User Frontend and woocomerce. I used this link: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-a-product-via-frontend-in-woocommerce/, as a guide followed instructions and I managed to make the form appear on the front-end. The only problem is that after submitting, the product is saved but the user is not redirected to any page and doesn't receive any thank you message. When I go to the back-end the newly created product appears but they are no image saved, no categories and no pricing. Can someone help me please.

Regards

Ted

Answer (score 0):

You may Try this new plugin which has a Lot of features
Features

[Woocommerce front-end Plugin](http://buykodo.com/woocommerce-front-end-plugin-launched/)

Comment: Dead link. Not an answer.